# How to secure user login in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login page with the following code to prevent any user from login to his profile without writing his username and password?

```
private void Page_Load()
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    Session.Remove("Authontocations");
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
  }
}
```

However, when I click the browser back button from the profile and then forward button from the login page I get-in the profile page without any effect from the up-mentioned code!! how do you think I can solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You must write logic in **Page_load** method as below. I am not sure where you have written your logic to clear the session.

```
private void Page_Load()

{

    if (!IsPostBack)

    {

        //You can write here the code, which you want to execute in the first time when the page is loaded.


    }

}
```